# Analysis of purely categorical data set

Tags: probability, categorical-data

Total statistics noob here. Imagine a data set like this, in which two categorical pieces of information ("SLOT"/"ITEM") are mapped:

```
PARTICIPANT 1
SLOT1: ITEM_A
SLOT2: ITEM_A
SLOT3: ITEM_C
SLOT4: ITEM_B
SLOT5: ITEM_F
```

There are hundreds of these records. All the "SLOT"s will always be mapped exactly once per participant, and all possible values are known. Now, when I visualize the data, it is super clear to see that there is a preference for certain ITEMs in certain SLOTs. But visual proof is not really enough here as it's very vague. Is there any statistical method I can employ to do so? Better yet, is there a way to tell how the slot **influences** the probability of a given ITEM?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Depending on what you mean by “influences”, there might be a simple approach. However, your use of that term alludes to causal inference, which is, in a few words, really hard. Thus, what do you mean when you write that word?

Comment: Hi Dave! Thanks for the quick reply. If there is something simple here, please let me know :) Best case scenario would be to have something I can state the following with: "SLOT2 produces a clear preference for ITEM_A, while shying people away from ITEM_F". But again, that is best case. Anything that helps me get some insights out of this kind of data is appreciated. Seems to me there must be something beyond taking min/max...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want some kind of causal inference, the problem gets (much) harder. However, if you just want to know the probability of variable $Y$ being a particular category given that variable $X$ is a particular category, the problem is easy: calculate it.

Let $X\in\{\text{dog},\text{cat},\text{bird}\}$ and $Y\in\{\text{bone},\text{yarn},\text{worm}\}$. If you want to know $P(Y=\text{worm}\vert X=\text{bird})$, calculate it as usual.

$P(Y=\text{worm}\vert X=\text{bird}) = \dfrac{
P(Y=\text{worm}\text{ AND }X=\text{bird})
}{
P(X=\text{bird})
}$

That is, calculate the probability of being a bird, and then calculate the probability of being both a bird and a worm. Equivalently, you can calculate the number of birds in your sample and then, out of those, consider how many have $Y=\text{worm}$. Then divide the number of birds with worms by the number of birds. The other eight pairings work analogously, as do all nine reverse pairings (e.g., $P(X=\text{bird}\vert Y=\text{worm})$ instead of $P(Y=\text{worm}\vert X=\text{bird})$, as these might be equal but need not be).

If you need explicit hypothesis testing, the $\chi^2$ test is a reasonable option. [The Wikipedia article has a good example using neighborhoods and blue collar/white collar.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) We have questions and answers on here that discuss the $\chi^2$ test, too, though none come to mind.

A more complicated approach is to think of this as a multinomial logistic regression analogue to the usual ANOVA, where we have a different multinomial distribution, depending on the category, much as the usual ANOVA has a different Gaussian distribution, depending on the category, though you wind up with the same conditional probabilities. Such a view of the probem, however, might help you in creating confidence intervals for differences in probabilities, much as you can do group-by-group comparisons in the usual ANOVA after an overall test of equality.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed!!!